# How can I forward a specific google apps mail account to a specific mail server?

Tags: email, hosting, g-suite, mailman

I've recently migrated a non-profit to google apps but I'm trying to keep the existing mailman listserv running. The problem is that all mail sent to @mydomain is now sent to google apps, but I'd like the listserv@mydomain to still go to the listserv machine. I've set up a listserv@mydomain account in google apps and tried to have it forwarded to listserv@*mail*.mydomain, which is the actual dns name of the box running the listserv but that doesn't work. Is there a way I can force mail sent to listserv@mydomain to be routed to listserv@*mail*.mydomain through some google apps or mx/dns sorcery?

thanx in adv.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a new subdomain in DNS for mail.mydomain.com with its own mx records pointing to your listserv machine.

Then the forwarding to listserv@mail.mydomain.com from google apps would work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set up a new subdomain. Just add an MX RR to mail.mydomain.com pointing to itself.